# django fixtures loaddata

Tags: python, django

I need to run a already existing django project.

I installed all dependencies, ran syncdb,migrate. Now App is running fine. But I want to load fixtures so that I can test the app with sample data.

I have three files fixtures/first.json /fixtures/thing.yaml fixtures/good_email.yaml

when I am running ./manage.py loaddata fixtures/good_email.yaml I 'm getting this error.

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'fixtures/good_email.yaml': Could not load
Myproject.MYclass(pk=78): columns kabal_id, email are not unique
```

How can I fix that, I don't want regenerate fixtures, but I need some fixes to my fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a unique contraint for two fields, but the data to import would violate this contraint (double value). You have to alter the data to be unique of remove the violating record.

Comment: I checked fixure file, file but unable to locate that line, as there are 20000 lines. please help

Comment: The pk (78) gives you an indicator which line to look at. I don't know the files so I can't tell you more.

Comment: Ok thank you, Is there any order to load fixtures files?